# Connecting a WPF app to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, database, xaml

In previous exercises I have been using a database file which is visually represented in the solution explorer and allowed me to access the tables of that file by referencing the database in the XAML as follows:

```
NORTHWNDEntities db = new NORTHWNDEntities();
```

In this exercise instead of dragging in a file I am connecting to a database that I have made in SQL server management studios. In the server explorer I can see that the database is connected as it has the connected Icon with the name

```
calry\calry.S00146154.dbo
```

My question is how do I reference this database in my XAML as done previous so that I can access the tables within it. This is what I have at the moment:
(I would also like to note that this database is not visually represented in the Solution explorer)

```
s00146154dboentities db = new s00146154dboentities();
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I found that the way to do this is as follows:

1. Connect to the desired database (tools -> Connect to Database -> Insert database info )
2. Add a new item to your solution and search 'LINQ' and select 'LINQ to SQL Classes'
3. In the new created window, drag the tables you want from the server explorer/tables and this will create the database in your WPF application
4. Add the following to your XAML with the information about your database:

   ```
   DatabaseNameDataContext VariableName = new DatabaseNameDataContext(
       Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseBranchConnectionString);
   ```
5. To test if its working I added the following into the public Mainwindow:

   ```
   InitializeComponent();

       if (VariableName.DatabaseExists())
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Data is in");
       }
   ```